# Merge output of multiple flink jobs and return single output

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have multiple flink jobs which has the same source of input kafka topic and the output format is also same.

Source -> flink job 1 -> output
Source -> flink job 2 -> output
Source -> flink job 3 -> output
Source -> flink job 4 -> output
.
.
.
Source -> flink job n -> output

output format is like `Object(pk: String, variable1: String, variable2: Boolean)`

I want to consume all the output and make the combined output let's say json of output array

Final required output `(pk: String, variable1: List[String], variable2: List[Boolean])`

P.S. - Some flink jobs might not return output for input as per implemented flink jobs logic and I am using scala as a language

Comment: Where is the output sent/processed? what do you intend to do after merging the different outputs? is there further processing, or it is sent to a sink?

Comment: After merging I want to sent it to sink

Comment: Since you want to combine the output of the streams, do you know what the bounds will be? For example, Will you combine records for 5 seconds and then forward to sink? or will you combine 100 records and write to the sink? It looks like you want to join the streams - https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/operators/joining/

Comment: It is not time bound or count bound, I want to combine per element, Or we can say if there are N jobs then I want to combine once all N jobs are completed but, here the problem is It is not necessary that every job will generate the output as some jobs applying filter in jobs so if element is filtered that job will generate output

Comment: Also, Joining of streams works when datastream are in a same job but, in this case datastream are in different jobs, not sure how to join them

Comment: If you are reading from Kafka, then typically you never have a "completed" job, as there can always be new data arriving. So what exactly do you mean by "once all N jobs are completed"?

Comment: I mean, once element is processed in all N jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating one more flink job which act as master job.
Input to this job is output of other N jobs. Since, those jobs were having `filter(condition)` I added one more datastream with `filter(!condition)` to make sure every job returns the output.
Also, added one datastream in master job which maintains the total job count and `connected` it with master job datastream. Representation of the same is in the following diagram.
[Flow of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsJcn.png)